# Is the pattern .\{-}\> equivalent to the move command e?

Tags: regular-expression, search, cursor-movement

What is the appropriate way to make a pattern that matches up until the point where the move command `e` would have moved to?

Consider this text: `texttext%0s: cookie` after performing `/%<CR>ve` the part `%0s` would be selected, this is the part I want to replace with something else.

I tried `:s/%.\{-}\>` which seems to match the right thing (as little as possible until end of word) but I'm not sure if it's 100% correct and how to interpret the manual:

`:help \>`

```
\>      Matches the end of a word: The previous char is the last char of a
        word.  The 'iskeyword' option specifies what is a word character.
```

`:help e`

```
e                       Forward to the end of word [count] inclusive.
                        Does not stop in an empty line.
```

Is the only difference that `e` moves past newlines?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is equivalent, except as you say it doesn't span lines.

First the `\>` matches a "end of a word" ( as defined by `iskeyword`). So it matches something that you could reach with the `e` command.

The important part is the `.\{-}`. With it the the expression `.\{-}\>` becomes "match from here to the next "end of word" in the same line. This is the same as `e`.

In contrast `.*\>` means "match from here to the last end of word in the current line".

The `.` does not match line breaks, but `\_.` does. So `%\_.\{-}\>` would match

```
%
word
```

Comment: Question title updated. One difference is that `e` reaches past line ends, which the pattern by default does not do (since `.` doesn't match newline).

Comment: @Moberg That with the title and text was nice chance for a joke. Should have put a smiley. You are right about end of line, will update.